# I/O Error on XSane frontend, but not on std out

Tags: linux, debian, xsane, sane

I have a Fujitsu ScanSnap ix500. It worked fine four weeks ago, but does not now. I did update my packages several times, so I'm not sure I have the same version of sane then I had before. Previously my scanner was connected through a USB-Hub and now its connected directly. I also currently have problems with policykit, but I assume they are not relevant here as I have the same problem when I start the programs as root.

-- Note: I've figured out that my underlying problem was that my version of sane-backend did not support xhci (usb 3) and the mainboard refused ehci. I could not fix it and use a different computer for scanning at the moment. This question is about the debugging options / logging toggles. I don't know how it ever worked on this machine, but it did. --

I've filed [a bug report](https://alioth.debian.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=410366&aid=315564&group_id=30186) concerning the error message quality. Additional insight might be gained from there.

When I start xsane I get the error message:

```
Fehler beim Öffnen des Geräts `fujitsu:ScanSnap iX500:119468':
 Fehler während Geräte I/O.
```

Translation:

```
open of device fujitsu:ScanSnap iX500:119468 failed: Error during device I/O
```

This only happens once, after that I can't connect to the scan snap at all anymore until I turn it off and on again, after that I get the above message again, once.

I attempted to get more details by starting xsane from command line:

```
$ xsane
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
```

So, I activated [additional debugging infos](https://blog.philippklaus.de/2009/02/howto-debug-sane/) with:

```
export SANE_DEBUG_DLL=255
```

That produced (reduced to fujitsu and general parts, [full output here](http://pastebin.com/gaNaFwXM))

```
$ xsane > xsane_output.txt
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
[sanei_debug] Setting debug level of dll to 255.
[dll] sane_init: SANE dll backend version 1.0.13 from sane-backends 1.0.25
[dll] sane_init/read_dlld: attempting to open directory `./dll.d'
[dll] sane_init/read_dlld: attempting to open directory `/etc/sane.d/dll.d'
[dll] sane_init/read_dlld: using config directory `/etc/sane.d/dll.d'
[dll] sane_init/read_dlld: considering /etc/sane.d/dll.d/hplip
[dll] sane_init/read_config: reading dll.d/hplip
[dll] add_backend: adding backend `hpaio'
[dll] sane_init/read_dlld: considering /etc/sane.d/dll.d/libsane-extras
[dll] sane_init/read_config: reading dll.d/libsane-extras
[dll] add_backend: adding backend `ls5000'
[dll] sane_init/read_dlld: done.
[dll] sane_init/read_config: reading dll.conf
[...]
[dll] add_backend: adding backend `fujitsu'
[...]
[dll] sane_get_devices
[...]
[dll] load: searching backend `fujitsu' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane'
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-fujitsu.so.1'
[dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-fujitsu.so.1'
[dll] init: initializing backend `fujitsu'
[dll] init: backend `fujitsu' is version 1.0.127
[...] 
[dll] sane_get_devices: found 1 devices
[dll] sane_open: trying to open `fujitsu:ScanSnap iX500:119468'
      # Program stays here while the i/o error message is displayed
[dll] sane_exit: exiting
[...]
[dll] sane_exit: calling backend `fujitsu's exit function
[...]
[dll] sane_exit: finished
```

I do not have `saned` running. When I tried to start it, it needed activation first and then nothing changed, so I deactivated it again.

When I use `scanimage` instead of `xsane`, I get this error message:

```
[dll] sane_get_devices: found 1 devices
[dll] sane_open: trying to open `fujitsu:ScanSnap iX500:119468'
scanimage: open of device fujitsu:ScanSnap iX500:119468 failed: Error during device I/O
[dll] sane_exit: exiting
```

I have no entries in `/var/log/syslog` at the time (besides the messages for plugging in and out of the scanner when I restart it). I did remove `libsane-hpaio`, but that didn't change anything either.

So, how do I get proper debugging messages to figure out whats my actual problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get better output information run this command:

```
export  SANE_DEBUG_SANEI_USB=128
```

It will tell you more about what sane does with the USB scanner, the next time you run `scanimage -L`.

For your underlying problem: sane updated the backend code, so it works with xhci. Update to 1.0.27 (or later).

If you can't wait for Debian to update their repository you can build xsane from scratch, but keep in mind that you should remove the packages from the distro first.
Also, its quite complicated to keep Xsane from the repository, but libsane* (aka sane_backends) from the sane project. So, you might prefer to wait until your distribution has properly packaged it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mention the distro?  Some distros have replaced syslog with journald (part of systemd).  Look up journalctl(1).

dmesg is sometimes useful.  In particular, there are obscure hints about xhci vs ScanSnap in the kernel log.  Not enough to help me, but they do show up.
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.usb.general/110579